# Power BI and JSON data

Tags: json, powerbi

Is it possible to make Power BI read JSON data? I've spent an entire day yesterday to figure out how to convert the JSON data into a readable table in Power Bi, but with no luck.

I tried googling for hours, but there is no proper documentation anywhere.

I'm retrieving a JSON payload from my website and when I try to import, it shows the data like this:

```
Record
Record
Record
Record
```

Maybe there are any tutorials I can follow? Or perhaps another alternative to Power BI that would properly read and structure my JSON data?

Comment: It looks like you have to create first a JSON request to retrieve the data. This can be done in Power Query as it's done here https://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/specifying-json-query-in-power-query-example-statistics-sweden/

Comment: Just besides the each Record (if headers), are you able to see any small box with two arrows, try clicking it.

Comment: This is the answer! Not sure why can't I accept it though..

Comment: JSON data is not, in general, tabular. However, an OData feed (in JSON or XML) is. If you control the source of your JSON data, consider delivering it via OData.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, just besides each Record (if headers), are you able to see any small box with two arrows, try clicking it.

Answer (score 4):

This Answer may help now..

First We have to convert this to table ->Click on the Icon in top left corner [image: Icon label : To Table]

Properties window will open. dont change anything Click on Ok.Now you can see the list converted to Column.

There is an arrow icon in the column -> Click on it

[image: Arrow Icon]

Main Step :In the property window **uncheck "use original column name as prefix"**

Here we go You can now use this result !

[image: You will get tabular result from JSON]

Refer Below Links :

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/

https://www.dutchdatadude.com/loading-multiple-json-files-using-power-query/

Comment: are there any known solutions for jsons that are deeply layered?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving data from a .json file brings in 'Records'. Each row of data is returned as a 'Record' which is a List. Each record in 'Records' is a  hyperlink that opens the row elements. You could convert the 'Records' into a table, but you get a Table with a single column which has all the records with each record a row from the original JSON data.

Here is a link to few more details:
http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2016/11/retrieving-json-data-in-power-bi.html