# Rest URL as data source to Power BI

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am using a Rest URL as data source to Power BI. That URL returns JSON data in the following format.

```
[
    {
        "Count": 8,
        "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "Title": "My Title 1"
    },
    {
        "Count": 10,
        "Email": "abcd@gmail.com",
        "Title": "My Title 2"
    }
]
```

PowerBI is able to pull data from the Rest URL provided. But it is showing data in the following format.

[image]

It is not showing data as table. I have searched for the solution but din't find one.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564718/power-bi-and-json-data) describes the same issue but the solution given did not work for me. (There is no **small box with two arrows beside each record** as explained in the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert list to table and arrows appear

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I converted my list to table and it works :)